# Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk Laravel 4 Deployment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 4 application to elastic beanstalk. But I face with 403, forbidden.

I followed the manual of Amazon for this process.

After filling the questions CLI 2.6 asks and `eb start`, the environment becomes usable and a file named optionsettings.(...)env is automatically being created.

I only change display_errors, EC2KeyName and document_root as:

```
display_errors=On
document_root=/public
EC2KeyName=blabla
```

I also created an `.ebextensions` folder and touch `01migrate.config` file in it.

Here is the content:

```
{
  "container_commands": {
    "artisan_migrate": {
      "command": "php artisan migrate --env=env",
      "leader_only": true
    },
    "artisan_migrate_2": {
      "command": "php artisan migrate --package=\"bla\/bla\ --env=env",
      "leader_only": true
    },
    "artisan_db_seed": {
      "command": "php artisan db:seed",
      "leader_only": true
    }
  }
}
```

When i use `git --status` for my already-existing git(hub) repo, it says `Working directory clean`.

I think everything is ready for deploy.

then I use `git aws.push` and the process starts.

A total of 7472 files are being written with forced update.

Here is the problems:
 - The env. link returns HTTP 403 with no access result.
 - .pem key not changes within EC2 configurations.
 - `document_root` is not `/public`
 - When I use aws console and set these properties, then ssh to EC2 instance, `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html/public` are both empty. (Where is my last commit which I can see under console.aws.amazon.com with exact same name of my latest github commit)

Here is the event logs:

> Environment update is starting.
>
> Deploying new version to instance(s).
>
> **[Instance: instance-number Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .**
>
> Command execution completed. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
>
> New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
>
> Environment update completed successfully.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. You'll need to look at your log.

My log was telling me that git was not installed, so the system was not able to successfully run composer.

So, I had to shell into ec2 and install git to get rid of the error.